# Deleting single record using primary key in JPA is not taking effect when this JPA call is made from catch block of @Async method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Async
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
void someMethod(Person p) {
   try{
    someApiCall();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // plain SQL query with @Query & @Transactional on it
    presonRepo.deletePersonViaId(p.getId());

    // throwing runtime exception once above query is executed
   }
}
```

Method is called like this ::

```
someService.someMethod()
```

Here I have also tried flush() but no effect once catch block is executed.
When I removed exception & simply returned the execution then it worked !!!

Comment: did you enable Async using `@EnableAsync` on your configuration class?

Comment: Can you also add more details how are you invoking this method ?

Comment: @EnableAsync is there on configuration class.

Comment: someService is invoking someMethod

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are you calling this method, but in general `@Async` has two limitations:

- it must be applied to public methods only
- self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – will not  work.

The reason why these rules are there is because:

1. public method so that it can be proxied.
2. self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

Comment: someMethod is called from another class, so two points you mentioned won't matter in this case. Async call is working as per expectation but query inside catch block is taking effect in DB even after getting executed properly. I tried flush also just after query execution but that also does not work.